# localStorage object is undefined in IE

Tags: javascript, local-storage, internet-explorer-9

I'm using localStorage in my JS application and I was wondering why IE9 claims `localStorage == undefined`. As far as I know, IE8 supports it, is here any way to get it working in the new version?

Comment: Are you testing this on a local HTML file with file `file://` protocol?

Comment: Typing `localStorage` in the Dev Tools console of the Platform Preview works for me on http sites

Comment: @Akexandre Jasmin oh you are right, I've forgot it does not work. Thank you.

Comment: Okay. I wrote an answer explaining the problem. You may want to accept it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Are you testing this on a local HTML file? i.e. a `file:///` URL?

localStorage is only available on HTTP websites. That hasn't changed in IE9 Dev Preview.

Comment: @AJ. Thanks. I had a suspicion that was the issue, but was still wondering what was wrong when testing in IE. I started running my test page from within an web app and it worked just fine across IE, FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 20):

IE 11 WORKS

All you need two do add file://127.0.0.1   to the trusted zones under the security
tab (NOTE: make sure https check box IS not checked)
add this line to the top or your script, depending on your code you may not need to unless you get could not connect to the internet.

```js
!localStorage && (l = location, p = l.pathname.replace(/(^..)(:)/, "$1$$"), (l.href = l.protocol + "//127.0.0.1" + p));

if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
    // Retrieve
    alert(localStorage.getItem("lastname"));
} else {
    alert("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...");
}
```

Comment: Great, this works! On my machine even without changing anything in the Security tabs etc. One note: this code throws a `Variable undefined in strict mode` error if you execute your code in strict mode. To solve, re-write in non-condensed mode (`if (!localStorage) { .... }`)

Answer (score 6):

Try to open the file like this

file://127.0.0.1/c$/pathtofile/file.html

Comment: I don't think that works.  Couldn't get it to work in IE11, at least.  Ah, well, use mongoose web server, it is small enough and then localSTorage works.

Comment: @daylight It works if you also add `file://127.0.0.1` to the list of trusted sites.

Comment: On IE11, this does not seem to work. I can't access a local file using `file://127.0.0.1/...`. I've add `file://127.0.0.1` to the IE Trusted Sites list.

Comment: Worked for me on IE11