# 'Storage' is undefined in IE9

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [localStorage object is undefined in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392032/localstorage-object-is-undefined-in-ie)

The following code gives me `SCRIPT5009: 'Storage' is undefined` in IE9. It works in Chrome, Safari, Firefox.

```
Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}
```

**udpate** I'm serving the page from Apache server, not accessing it from local file system so the following don't apply:

[localStorage object is undefined in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392032/localstorage-object-is-undefined-in-ie)

[local storage in IE9 fails when the website is accessed directly from the file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706006/local-storage-in-ie9-fails-when-the-website-is-accessed-directly-from-the-file-s)

**update 2** found problem, see my answer.

Comment: Do you have a DOCTYPE on the page?  Is the page running in "Compatibility Mode"?

Comment: I didn't specify DOCTYPE. It's running "Quirks" mode

Comment: @dev.e.loper: That's probably the issue.  It needs to run in "IE9 Mode".

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706006/local-storage-in-ie9-fails-when-the-website-is-accessed-directly-from-the-file-s

Comment: I'm serving the page from Apache server, not accessing it from local file system

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I must specify DOCTYPE `<!DOCTYPE html>` Even though other browsers don't care IE does.

Thanks to @Rocket Hazmat for pointing it out.

Without DOCTYPE, IE goes into Quirks mode. With DOCTYPE, IE is goes into Standards mode. My guess is that IE needs to be in Standards mode in order to access HTML5 features.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing here...

IE 9 does not seem to support localStorage when run on a local filesystem: [local storage in IE9 fails when the website is accessed directly from the file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706006/local-storage-in-ie9-fails-when-the-website-is-accessed-directly-from-the-file-s)

More detail can be found here: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/03/10/using-html5-web-storage-for-interprocess-communication.aspx

So you can either run it on an external server - or check if it is supported in your script:

```
if ("localStorage" in window && window["localStorage"] != null) {

    // Local storage supported

}
```

Comment: I'm serving the page from Apache server, not accessing it from local file system. Also, I belive IE9 supports storage http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

Comment: Yes it does! But it seems not on a local filesystem. That was my guess ;)