# Localstorage getItem and setItem not working in ie 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, local-storage

I have tried searching through SO where i get some sort of idea how to enable setItem and getItem in ie9 but no use it was not working in ie 9

```
function assignValue() {
    var checkedRadioValue = -1;
    if (document.getElementById("ug").checked)
    {
        checkedRadioValue = 1;
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("pg").checked)
    {
        checkedRadioValue = 2;
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("cu").checked)
    {
        checkedRadioValue = 3;
    }
    //localStorage.setItem("CheckedRadioValue", checkedRadioValue);

    localStorage.setItem("CheckedRadioValue", checkedRadioValue);
}
```

Actually i am trying some thing like this for ie9

```
if(window.localStorage) { 
    localStorage.setItem("CheckedRadioValue", checkedRadioValue);
}
```

like this I am trying to get the value using localstorage in ie9 this was working perfectly in chrome, firefox

```
var checkedRadioValue = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("CheckedRadioValue"));
    if (checkedRadioValue != -1) {
        if (checkedRadioValue === 1) {
            $('.local_Field ').each(function() {
                $(this).rules("remove","required");
            });
        }
        else if (checkedRadioValue === 3){
            $('.local_Field').each(function() {
                $(this).rules("remove","required");
            });
            $("#edu_info").hide();
            $(".local_Field").removeClass('required_Field');
            //$('.local_Field ').addClass('chumma');
        }
        else{
            $('.local_Field ').each(function() {
                $(this).rules("add","required");
            });
             $(".local_Field").addClass('required_Field');
        };
        //localStorage.removeItem("CheckedRadioValue");
    }
```

This what the error i am geting in IE10

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'getItem' of undefined or null reference
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [localStorage object is undefined in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392032/localstorage-object-is-undefined-in-ie)

Comment: @Pablo i have checked it in the same it was not working some how :(

Comment: So you are serving that page from a server, aren't you?

Comment: yes i am doing it from the server using localhost