# IE 11 - Loacalstorage with an event listener to refresh the pages in other Browser tabs when logged out from one tab, does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, internet-explorer-11, browser-tab

I am sure , this question in some or the other way, has surfaced in SO a lot of times, but nothing really helped me.

I will get to the point,

I have opened multiple tabs of my application. And while logging out from one tab, should refresh the other tabs.
So the code i wrote is this,

```
localStorage.setItem('logout-event', 'logout' + Math.random());
```

and

```
 window.addEventListener('storage', function (event) {

if (event.key == 'logout-event') {
    $('<div>You are logged out. The page will be refreshed.</div>', { id: "confirmBox" }).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                window.location.reload(true);
            },                
        }
    });
    }
}, false);
```

This works in every other browsers, except IE. I know there are options like sessionStorage, postMessage etc etc. I would be grateful if i get an answer which is similar to localstorage, but that works for IE.

Thank you.

Edit: I should have mentioned that I know IE 11 doesn't support it, as I had researched on it for quite some time, and I am looking for an alternate inbuilt code approach. I am sorry, but I do not want to know whether IE support it or not, I want to achieve the task that I have mentioned above in an alternate approach without any new references or extensions, if any. Thank you for all the responses. I am currently trying to make custom events. Not sure that will work. Meanwhile looking for a good alternate approach. Thank you again everyone.

Comment: try to use polyfillfs ... like https://www.npmjs.com/package/localstorage-browser-polyfill

Comment: Are you trying to running your site on local machine? I suggest you to try to host it in IIS for testing purpose and then try to check the result.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit below-mentioned sites for more information about browser compatibility of storage API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_storageevent

https://caniuse.com/#search=storage

as the storage event API is not supported with IE but the latest version of edge<18.

Answer (score 0):

Though this already has a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392032/localstorage-object-is-undefined-in-ie), I'll still explain how it works. When you're testing a local file `window.localStorage` is not accessible in IE. You can verify that by typing `window` in console and scrolling down to local storage. It should say something like **Permission denied**. While you can can still access the localStoarage as a HTTP website. There's a fix to this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392032/localstorage-object-is-undefined-in-ie) (The second answer).

Edit - For IE if you actually check localStorage in window Object. You will see **null**, It says **Permission Denied** in Edge.